# How to sort C++ map keys with std::greater?

Tags: c++

I'm creating a `std::map<int, int>` in C++ that I'd prefer to have they keys sorted from highest to lowest instead of the default sort order. My research lead me to [std::greater](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/greater/) which looked promising but when trying to use it I'm getting a compile error:

> invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)

My map declaration is:

```
std::map<int, int, std::greater<int> > numMap;
```

And the error is getting thrown from this function:

```
void Row::addNumber(int num, int pos) {
    numMap.insert(num, pos);
}
```

Answers to similar questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14828476/confusion-about-using-stdless-and-stdgreater-with-stdsort) include parenthesis in the declaration, i.e. std::greater**()** - but when I include those I get multiple errors regarding a function returning a function.

Comment: isnt your problem solved when you read the map backwards? just saying.

Comment: Are you saying that you don't get that same error when you use `std::map`'s default comparator?  Because that should not matter one bit in this case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem – call of `std::map::insert` member function with invalid parameters: there are two integer values provided; but there **must be** `std::pair<int, int>`. Please see the reference: [std::map::insert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert).

## Preferable option

For **convenience** (just **not to repeat** the map type parameters), create a `typedef` for the map:

```
typedef std::map<int, int> IntMap;
```

The `std::map` has type definition for `std::pair` (pair representation) – `std::map::value_type`.
So, for example, if there is a `std::map<int, int>` the `std::map::value_type` would be `std::pair<int, int>`.

Use the `std::map::value_type` constructor (`IntMap::value_type` in this case):

```
class Row {
public:
    void Row::addNumber(int num, int pos)
    {
        m_numMap.insert(IntMap::value_type(num, pos));
    }

private:
    typedef std::map<int, int> IntMap;
    IntMap m_numMap;
};
```

## Alternatives:

1. Use `std::make_pair()` function:

   ```
   #include <utility>

   ...

   void Row::addNumber(int num, int pos)
   {
       numMap.insert(std::make_pair(num, pos));
   }
   ```
2. Directly use `std::pair` constructor:

   ```
   void Row::addNumber(int num, int pos)
   {
       numMap.insert(std::pair<int, int>(num, pos));
   }
   ```

Comment: Very much this. The insert function doesn't work the way you might expect it to. :(

Comment: Ah thanks, I had assumed C++'s map insert functioned the same way as Java's map.put - clearly I should have researched that more :-(

Comment: @Exupery, by the way, if you have used `HashMap` class in Java, you might want to use `std::unordered_map` class (available since **C++11**) – hash-map container.

Comment: Thanks, good to know for future use, though in this particular instance I do need the map to be ordered.

Answer (score 5):

A bit more pedantic than Sergey's answer (which also definitely works), instead Use:

```
typedef std::map<int, int, std::greater<int> > MyMap;
MyMap numMap;

void Row::addNumber(int num, int pos)
{
    numMap.insert(MyMap::value_type(num, pos));
}
```

The benefit being that if you change the type of the map, you have less code to change later. And much less likely but still possible, if the implementation of `std::map` changes its `value_type` from `std::pair` to something else (in a future version of the `stl`), you are impervious to that change.

Comment: +1, yes, you're right: `std::map::value_type` is very convenient (not to repeat the parameters of `std::map` type).