# greater/less function objects in C++

Tags: c++, sorting, functor

I have gone through the function object documentation for greater, less. Though I do sort of understand what is in it, I don't get it yet. Will using a greater sort my container in an ascending or descending order? I am especially confused because the following two lines seem to be doing opposite things.

```
std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, std::greater<int> > q2;

for(int n : {1,8,5,6,3,4,0,9,7,2})
    q2.push(n);

print_queue(p2);
```

This prints 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9. But,

```
int x[10] = { 1,3,5,7,9,2,4,6,8,10 };
std::sort(x,x+10,std::greater<int>());
```

Printing this would give 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1.

It would be nice if someone could describe how 'greater' works in my examples, instead of just saying how 'greater' works in general.

Comment: You may find this helpful [confusion about using std::less and std::greater with std::sort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14828476/confusion-about-using-stdless-and-stdgreater-with-stdsort)

Comment: @MikeT: Did go through that, still had the confusion. Getting more sense from Dai and StoryTeller's answers though, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will be ascending , you'll always pop the smallest element of the queue. A priority queue sorts in reverse to the order relation it is given.

The default template definition looks like this:

```
template<
    class T,
    class Container = std::vector<T>,
    class Compare = std::less<typename Container::value_type>
> class priority_queue;
```

It applies `less<>()(lhs, rhs)` to get the "biggest" rhs element. But in your case, it will apply `greater<>()(lhs, rhs)` to get the "biggest" rhs element (which will of course be the smallest).

`std::sort`, on the other hand, preserves the order type you give it. So `std::less` will sort in ascending order, and `std::greater` in descending order.

Comment: In the default template definition, priority_queue uses std::less. So, by default, without using any external functor like greater, shouldn't it print in an ascending order? Why does it follow descending by default then? Sorry, seem to partly get it now. Still can't see why it would get the "biggest" rhs element though.

Comment: @AshwinBaskaran, the template treats the functor type as a black box. The black box orders the elements according to some some rule. There is always a "biggest" element according to the rule, but it doesn't have to be "biggest" according to the regular ordering of the integers, does it make it clearer?

Comment: Yes, I can understand that now. The greater/less functors basically sort the numbers according to a rule. By default, priority_queue uses std::less. And I think here, the rule is "biggest" number is the one with the lowest integer value. So, that should appear first. And wouldn't the priority_queue follow ascending order by default then? I know I am going wrong somewhere, just can't figure out where.

Comment: @AshwinBaskaran, a priority_queue takes the "biggest" number according to the rule. So `std::less<int>(1,2) == true` and the queue orderes `2` before `1`. For `std::greater<int>(2, 1) == true` and `1` is ordered before `2`.

Comment: I can see it now. I had the ordering part confused. With your original answer and the previous comment, it looks obvious to me now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`std::greater<int>` inverses the sort-order of integers.

`std::priority_queue` [dequeues the next largest element *by default*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue), so by using `std::greater<int>` you're inverting this so it dequeues the next smallest element instead.

Similarly, `std::sort` will sort elements in ascending order by default, but by using `std::greater<int>` you'll see a descending sort-order.

Comment: This makes it easier to understand. So, is it safe to think greater<int> would always reverse the natural sorting-order for all containers/container adapters?